# How to read rotary encoder

Tags: c++, arduino

Hello I'm wondering why doesn't this code work, since the encoder is working 100% and I'm sure that the chunk of code that is supposed to do the reading part is working as well, please check the code if you can, there has to be some kind of really dumb mistake I guess .. or is it possible that the arduino uno isn't capable of reading so many pins ? Here is the code

Problem is being cause by the getTemperature function

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#define LDR A0
#define Fan 3
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
#define BACKLIGHT 5
    #define outputA 6
    #define outputB 7

LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8);
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

float temperature = 0;

int start = 0 , start1 = 0;
unsigned long timer = 0;
unsigned long tx;

    int counter = 0;
    int aState, aLastState;

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(Fan , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A1,INPUT);
  pinMode(BACKLIGHT,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,INPUT_PULLUP);
  setEncoder();  
}


boolean isMin=true;
int temp1=4,temp2=15;
long pressed=millis();
void loop(void)
{
  encoderRead();
  getTemperature();
  if(digitalRead(4)==LOW&&millis()-pressed>=1000){
    isMin = !isMin;
    pressed=millis();
    tx=millis();
  }
  if(isMin){
    //temp2 = map(counter , 0 , 100 , 1 , 60);                       //For setting 15 min time from range of 1-60 minutes
    //tx=millis();
  }else{
    //temp1 = map(counter , 0 , 100 , 1 , 24);                       //For setting 5 hour time from range of 1-24 hour
    //tx=millis();
  }
  String s = "HODINY: "+String(temp1)+"\nMINUTY: "+String(temp2);
  Serial.println(s);
  Serial.println(counter);
  String t1 , t2;

  if (temp1 < 10)
    t1 = " " + String(temp1);
  else
    t1 = String(temp1);

  if (temp2 < 10)
    t2 = " " + String(temp2);
  else
    t2 = String(temp2);

  if (millis() - tx < 600000) {                                            //LCD displays stops every 10 minutes (600000milli seconds)
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Temp: " + String(temperature));
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("T1: " + String(t1) + " H T2: " + String(t2) + " M");
    digitalWrite(BACKLIGHT,HIGH);
  }
  else
    digitalWrite(BACKLIGHT,LOW);                                          //No data on display

                                                                          //1. LDR - detects LIGHTS ON (daytime)
  if (analogRead(LDR) >= 700 && start == 0) {                             //If it is day time
    start = 1;                                                             //Set start (day) as 1
    start1 = 0;                                                            //Set start1 (night) as 0
    timer = millis();                                                      //Reset timer
    digitalWrite(Fan , HIGH);                                               //Arduino has FANS OFF
    //Serial.println("ZACAL SOM CAST JEDNA");
  }
                                                                           //1. LDR - detects LIGHTS OFF (night time)
  else if (analogRead(LDR) <700 && start1 == 0) {                        //If it is night time
    start = 0;                                                             //Set start (day) as 0
    start1 = 1;                                                            //Set start1 (night) as 1
    timer = millis();                                                      //Reset timer
    digitalWrite(Fan , LOW);                                              //Turn ON Fan When nite time is detected Arduino has FANS ON
    //Serial.println("ZACAL SOM CAST DVA");
  }

  //DAYTIME PROGRAM
  if (start == 1) {
    digitalWrite(Fan , HIGH);                                               //2. Arduino has FANS OFF and waits for temp to reach >90 deg (temperature rises during daytime)
    getTemperature();                                                      //3. Once >90 deg, Arduino runs "Timer A" for 15 minutes (set by pot #A)
    //Serial.println(temperature);
    if (temperature >= 90)                                                 //If temperature is greater then 90
    {
      start = 2;                                                           //Go to step 2
      timer = millis();                                                    //Reset timer
    }
  }
  else if (start == 2) {                                                   //Step2- If it is day time and temperature is greater 90 and timer is then 1-60 minutes set by pot
    if((millis() - timer)/1000 <= temp2 * 60) {                           //Wait for timer 'A' to expire, Arduino has fans off
        //Serial.println((millis() - timer)/1000);
        digitalWrite(Fan , HIGH);
        //Serial.println("CAKAM TIME A");
    }else{
    getTemperature();
    digitalWrite(Fan,LOW);
    start = 3;                                                             //Go to step 3
    timer = millis();                                                      //Reset timer
    }                       
  }
  else if (start == 3 && (millis() - timer)/1000 <= temp1  * 3600) {        //Step3-If it is day time and timer is less then 1-24 hour set by pot
    getTemperature();                                                      //5. Also immediately after 15 minute “Timer A” expires, Arduino runs “Timer B” that runs for 4 hours (set by pot#B).
    if(temperature>=77){                                                   //When temperature is more than 77deg turn on the FAN
      getTemperature();
      digitalWrite(Fan,LOW);
      //Serial.println("ZNIZUJEM TIMER B");
    }
    else if (temperature < 77){                                             //If regular daytime temperature is less then 76 turn OFF FAN
      digitalWrite(Fan , HIGH);                                              //Turn OFF Fan
      //Serial.println("STOJIM");
      getTemperature();
    }
    //Serial.println("CAKAM TIMER B");
  }
  else if(start ==3) {                                                      //If it is day time and timer is greater then 1-24 hour set by pot
    start = 1;                                                              //6. Once 4 hour “Timer B” expires and temperatures have been regulated at >78 <77 during this time, FAN OFF. LOOP TO #2 above (daytime program).
    //Serial.println("ZNOVA ZACINAM DEN");
  }

  //NIGHT TIME PROGRAM
  if (start1 == 1 && (millis() - timer)/1000 < temp1 * 3600) {              //Step1-If it is night time and timer is less then 1-24 hour set by pot
    getTemperature();                                                       //3. Also, as soon as nite time is detected by LDR “Timer B” (set by pot #B) is to run for 4 hours.
    if (temperature >= 70) {                                                //If temperature is greater then 70 turn ON FAN
      //Serial.println("ZNIZUJEM NOC");
      digitalWrite(Fan , LOW);                                             //Turn ON Fan
    }
    else if (temperature <= 69){                                             //If temperature is less= then 69 turn OFF FAN
      //Serial.println("ZVYSUJEM NOC");                         
      digitalWrite(Fan , HIGH);                                              //Turn OFF Fan
    }
  }
  else if (start1 == 1 && (millis() - timer)/1000 >= temp1 * 3600) {        //If it is night and timer is greater then 1-24 hour set by pot
    getTemperature();
    if (temperature >= 66) {                                                //Timer 'B' expired, FANs on until temp is lower than 66deg.
      //Serial.println("KONIEC BCKA IDEM CAKAT NA MENEJ AKO 66");                                             
      digitalWrite(Fan , LOW);                                                
      getTemperature();
    }
                                                                            //Once temperature is lower than 66deg = Arduino runs “Timer A” for 15 minutes (set by pot #A)
    else if(temperature < 66){
      digitalWrite(Fan , HIGH);                                              //Turn OFF Fan
      start1 = 3;                                                           //Go to step 2
      //Serial.println("MENEJ AKO 66");
      timer = millis();                                                     //Reset timer
    }
  }
  else if (start1 == 3 && (millis() - timer)/1000 > temp2 * 60) {           //If it is night time and timer is greater then 1-60 minutes set by pot
                                                                            //7. After “Timer A” expires, LOOP TO #2 (night time program)
    start1 = 1;                                                             //Go to step 1 night time
    timer = millis();                                                       //Reset timer
    //Serial.println("ZACINAM ZNOVA NOCICKU");
  }
}

void getTemperature(){
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  temperature = sensors.getTempFByIndex(0);
}
void encoderRead(){
  aState = digitalRead(outputA);
  if(aState != aLastState){
    if(digitalRead(outputB)!=aState){
      if(counter<=100){
        counter++;
      }
    }else{
      if(counter>=0){
       counter--;
      }
    }
  }
  aLastState = aState;
}
void setEncoder(){
  pinMode(outputA,INPUT);
  pinMode(outputB,INPUT);
  aLastState = digitalRead(outputA);
}
```

And this is the code that I've tested and the readigs were just fine

```
#define outputA 6
#define outputB 7

int counter = 0;
int aState,aLastState;
void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(4,INPUT_PULLUP);
  setEncoder();  
}

void loop() {
  encoderRead();
  Serial.println(counter);
}

void encoderRead(){
  aState = digitalRead(outputA);
  if(aState != aLastState){
    if(digitalRead(outputB)!=aState){
      if(counter<=100){
        counter++;
      }
    }else{
      if(counter>=0){
       counter--;
      }
    }
  }
  aLastState = aState;
}
void setEncoder(){
  pinMode(outputA,INPUT);
  pinMode(outputB,INPUT);
  aLastState = digitalRead(outputA);
}
```

Comment: Scale back your ambitions. Back up your code and try to reproduce the error with less and less code until you have reduced your way back to the code that does work. The error will likely be in the code that was last removed, and that is much less code to have to puzzle out. Use [mcve] as inspiration. In general, start with working code and add slowly and carefully, testing each change  You'll rarely find yourself in a position where you have a hundred lines of code and no clue where the error is because usually the error will be in or exposed by the code just added..

Comment: well now I know that the error is being cause by the getTemperature function

Comment: If the code is large and doing lots of things then it may be taking too long between calling the encoder function and you may be missing pulses.  In this case it may be better to use an interrupt to read the encoder.  This is one of those places where the pulses are short enough that interrupts are reasonable.

Comment: I just figured it out, ended up doing for loop where I always called the encoderRead function 100 times :D guess I'll have to take a look on interrupts, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was too long, arduino was missing signals, interrupts are required for such long code to work with rotart encoder.